# Greedy algorithm for cellphone base station problem, Algortihm Manual

Tags: algorithm, runtime, greedy

I have attempted the question:
Let’s consider a long, quiet country road with houses scattered very
sparsely along it. (We can picture the road as a long line segment, with
an eastern endpoint and a western endpoint.) Further, let’s suppose that
despite the bucolic setting, the residents of all these houses are avid cell
phone users. You want to place cell phone base stations at certain points
along the road, so that every house is within four miles of one of the base
stations.
Give an efficient algorithm that achieves this goal, using as few base
stations as possible.

My solution:
For each house on the line create a job interval entry with start S[h] = house distance from east - 4, and finish F[h] = house distance from east + 4

Then run interval scheduling algorithm (but without preprocessing sort).

The number of base towers will be the number of jobs returned by interval scheduling.

The idea was that we'll need only 1 tower per non overlapping job (house) as all the other jobs (houses) are covered by the job with which they overlapped with.

Is this idea right?

Also, would the run time of this algorithm be O(n) where n is the number of houses

Btw if there's anything wrong with my question please tell me :) This is my first post so not sure exactly how to structure it.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Do you have an array of house coordinates sorted in ascending order? If not, I am sure that this problem cannot be solved without initial sorting of houses coordinates, which is not a `O(n)` time complexity.

Comment: We are told we are given a "long line segment, with an eastern endpoint and a western endpoint". I thought that the houses on this line segment are implicitly sorted by distance from the western point (which can be treated as 0). As such going through the line segment starting at west most end each next house can be at the same point or more east. Thus, processing houses in order gives us sorting by finish time. I guess we can assume this can be represented as an array?

Comment: But yes if we can't assume that then I agree it's not O(n)

Answer (score 0):

First, Sort the houses according to their locations in O(n \log n).
Next, select the locations of the base towers according to the locations above.
Assuming the location of the first house is "p" place the first base tower at location "p + 4" miles, and remove all the houses with cell phone service (houses 4 miles within that tower) from the list.
Repeat the procedure till all houses have been covered.